# error al instalar tinytext en r studio

Tags: r, rstudio

[image: compre un curso en udemy de estadistica descriptiva en r y buneno, tenia que isntalar esto, no se por que me salta este error, tengo desactivado el antivirus y windows defender]
compre un curso en udemy de estadistica descriptiva en r y buneno, tenia que isntalar esto, no se por que me salta este error, tengo desactivado el antivirus y windows defender

Comment: ¿Desde dónde estas instalando `tinytext`? ¿Desde el mismo Rmd? ¿Con que comado?

Comment: desde la consola de Rstudio
el comando: tinytex::install_tinytex()

Comment: es el que me sugiere cuando intento hacer un rmd en pdf

Answer (score 0):

Instale `miktex` y ahí empece a tener errores, uno tras otro en la ejecución:

> ! Sorry, but
>   C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe
>   did not succeed.
>
> ! The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
>   again:
>
> !   C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
>
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile aa.tex. See
>   https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See aa.log
>   for more info. Ejecución interrumpida

Actualize `Miktex`, seguí teniendo errores, elimine todos los archives que había creado, active la opción **always install missed packages on the fly** y por fin abrió el pdf